# Monotouch: can I use "Upgrade Current Target for iPad command"

Tags: xamarin.ios

Is it possible to use the XCode "Upgrade Current Target for iPad" command to assist in converting a Monotouch created app for the iPhone to make a "universal app"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way I know of is to use the option 'Create iPad Version' in Interface Builder (IB) for each of your XIBs.  From there you will have to save the XIB and hook up iPad versions of your controllers.

It actually might be easier to start a new "Universal" project and import your old code in.